# sound.Play() is not playing custom sound file in Garry's Mod

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

No custom sound files are played, but in-game sound files are played.
Sound file has 44100Hz
I have tried stereo and mono
mp3 and ogg I have also tried

```
local soundFile = "addons/testaddon/sound/testsound.wav"

hook.Add("KeyPress", "myTestAddon", function(ply, key)
    if key == IN_JUMP then
        sound.Play(soundFile, ply:GetPos(), 75, 100, 1)
        print("Test")
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

> This should be [...] a file path **relative** to the sound/ folder.

https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/sound.Play

In your case just use "testsound.wav".